# Update foreign key when primary key changes, when passing data from SQLite to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I’m developing an android application, where I have a SQLite database.

My application sends the data in this database to a MySQL database in the web.
The problem is that various devices can sends data from the SQLite to MySQL, and I need to update the foreign keys in the MySQL database every time I send data, because the primary keys always change when the information goes from the SQLite to the MySQL database.

I used UPDATE CASCADE for every foreign key, but it doesn’t work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

ON UPDATE CASCADE has an effect only when you're actually running an UPDATE statement.

You have to keep track of how the IDs change manually, and insert all data with the new IDs.